# Z transform and non-$\ell^{1}$ causal sequences

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence, z-transform

Consider a complex sequence $h[n]$, such that:

- if $n < 0 \Rightarrow h[n] = 0 $
- $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \left|h[n]\right|$ diverges
- $H(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} h[n]z^{-n}$ converges uniformly $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| = 1$.

My questions are:

1. Does it exist? (If not: why?)
2. If yes, which is an example or a set of such a sequence?
3. Can I state that the lower bound of the region of convergence of $H(z)$ is $1$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It is a fundamental fact that every Laurent series converges uniformly and absolutely in its region of convergence.

If $H(z)$ admits such a Laurent series expansion for $|z|=1$, then 
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}|h[n]z^{-n}|= \sum^\infty_{n=0}|h[n] |$$ necessarily converges, which leads to a contradiction.